# Can you get strongly-type hits from InnerHits using NEST 2?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the NEST 2 client to perform queries against our Elasticsearch.

We've got a query that queries against an array of Nested documents and use .InnerHits() to include the matches of the nested documents in the result.

Is there a way to strongly type the results of the InnerHits to a particular POCO class instead of dynamically accessing the resulting fields?

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is; [Here's an example from the integration tests for inner hits](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Tests/Search/Request/InnerHitsUsageTests.cs); the principles are the same for any search that can return inner hits

```
public interface IRoyal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}


[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "Name")]
public abstract class RoyalBase<TRoyal> : IRoyal
    where TRoyal : class, IRoyal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class King : RoyalBase<King>
{
    public List<King> Foes { get; set; }
}

public class Prince : RoyalBase<Prince> { }
public class Duke : RoyalBase<Duke> { }
public class Earl : RoyalBase<Earl> { }
public class Baron : RoyalBase<Baron> { }
```

1. Each `King` has a list of other `King`s who are the foes of the king.
2. A `King` has n `Prince` children and
3. Each `Prince` has n `Duke` children
4. Each `Duke` has n `Earl` children
5. Each `Earl` has n `Baron` children

So, we have four descending Parent/Child relationships. The id to use for each document is the `Name` property on the document.

An example of a strongly typed inner hit search with such a setup would be

```
var response = client.Search<Duke>(s => s
    .Index(index)
    .InnerHits(ih => ih
        .Type<Earl>("earls", g => g
            .Size(5)
            .InnerHits(iih => iih
                .Type<Baron>("barons")
            )
            .FielddataFields(p => p.Name)
        )
    )
);
```

And then handling the response, demonstrating a couple of ways for strongly typed access

```
foreach (var hit in response.Hits)
{
    // each hit here is a Hit<ILazyDocument> i.e.
    // no strongly typed access
    var earlHits = hit.InnerHits["earls"].Hits;

    // strongly typed access to documents using
    // .Documents<T>()
    var earls = earlHits.Documents<Earl>();

    foreach (var earlHit in earlHits.Hits)
    {
        // use Source.As<T> to access source strongly typed
        var earl = earlHit.Source.As<Earl>().Name;

        var baronHits = earlHit.InnerHits["barons"];

        // strongly typed access to documents
        var baron = baronHits.Documents<Baron>();

        // do something with baron documents
    }
}
```

Types need to be known when accessing response because the client does not store or persist the relationship of name of the inner hit to the C# type.

Inner hits are internally deserialized to Json.Net `JObject` types, with `.Source.As<T>()` and `.Documents<T>()` using `JToken.ToObject<T>()` within Json.Net to perform the conversion.